# Jacobian change of variables formula for $p$-adic valued integration?

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

Let $k$ be a $p$-adic field.  It's possible to make sense of the Haar measure $\mu_{\operatorname{Haar}}$ on $k^n$ as a $k$-valued measure and define integrals

$$\int\limits_{k^n} f(x_1, ... , x_n) d\mu_{\operatorname{Haar}}(x)$$

for suitable analytic $k$-valued functions $f$ on $k^n$.  If $\varphi: U \rightarrow V$ is a $k$-analytic isomorphism between open sets $U$ and $V$ in $k^n$, then for suitable *complex* valued functions $f: k^n \rightarrow \mathbb C$, we have a change of variables formula

$$\int\limits_V f(x)dx_1 \cdots dx_n = \int\limits_U f \circ \varphi(x) |D_{\varphi}(x)|dx_1 \cdots dx_n$$
where $D_{\varphi}$ is the determinant of the Jacobian of $\varphi$, and $dx_1 \cdots dx_n$ is the (real valued) Haar measure on $k^n$.  Is there an analogue of this formula for $k$-valued measures and $k$-analytic maps $f: k^n \rightarrow k$?  Something like

$$\int\limits_V f(x) d\mu_{\operatorname{Haar}}(x) = \int\limits_U f \circ \varphi(x) D_{\varphi}(x) d\mu_{\operatorname{Haar}}(x)$$
(without the absolute value)?

Comment: What kind of "p-adic Haar measure" are you using here? Obviously whether or not such a thing exists depends on what properties that you want it to have, but for most reasonable definitions, such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't really know.  The motivation behind this is I'm repeatedly encountering two $p$-adic Jacobian determinants whose absolute values are equal (which I determine via the usual complex change of variables formula).  I want to say that they are actually equal, so I was hoping I could see this by some $p$-adic valued integration.

Comment: So you "don't really know" how to justify the assertion you make in the first sentence of your own question?

Comment: No I don't $\space$

Comment: @David Loeffler: Maybe a more interesting question would be whether there is some sort of p-adic measure / distribution / something for which the stated change of variables formula holds, at least for some sufficiently nice class of functions?